# Check if on or more array elements in a specific position in string

Tags: php

I have a String with some specific abbreviations. The String can contain one, more or no abbreviation. 
Then I have an Array with the abbreviation as elements.

I'm searching for a solution to give the matched abbreviation in a new array back.

For example:

```
$abbreviation = array('HSGE', 'DFVC');
$string = 'This is a abbreviation HSGE and here is the other DFVC";
```

The output should be:

```
$output = ([0] => HSGE [1] => DFVC);
```

Maybe it's easy but I am new with this.

Comment: What about the output in this string ``'This is a abbreviation HSGE and here is the other DFVC, another DFVC one and one more HSGE'`` ?

Comment: How is this related to `mysql`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A simple solution using [array_intersect](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-intersect.php):

```
array_intersect(explode(' ',$string), $abbreviation)
```

Answer (score 0):

You should use `strpos` to retrieve the position of the abreviation in the string.
http://php.net/manual/en/function.strrpos.php

If the abreviation is not in the string then `strpos` will return FALSE

So a solution is to loop through your abbreviation array and check if this abreviation is used in the string with strpos.

Answer (score 0):

You can create a loop `foreach` element of your abbreviations array and search for the position of every element in the string with `strpos`, then if you find it, you can add the abbreviation to the resulting array with `array_push`.

You can find what you need here:

http://php.net/manual/en/function.strpos.php

http://php.net/manual/en/control-structures.foreach.php

http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-push.php